# What game is being played in this Crash Course: Computer Science video?

Tags: game-identification

I was watching Crash Course: Computer Science, and partway through today's video, they showed someone playing a splitscreen FPS, but with the game being blurred.

In case the video doesn't show at the right time: it is at the 5:06 mark.

What game is the person playing?

Comment: It looks vaguely like Battlefield 3 to me, but it's really hard to tell.

Comment: Actually there is no mini-map in the right side of the screen so probably not Battlefield 3

Comment: @Nzall You can use [this](https://www.dreamstime.com/stock-footage-man-playing-shooter-video-game-back-view-shown-big-screen-video45885438) gif, which contains the same scene that is longer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like Far Cry 3.

Link: [Youtube video of Far Cry 3 split screen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TF33Afwzrc8).

Comment: I think you're right. Another thing I noticed between the two videos is the gun swaying while the character sprints.  Looks near identical.  The right side of the HUD also looks like a match.  Nice find.

Comment: You can see a longer gif of the scene [here](https://www.dreamstime.com/stock-footage-man-playing-shooter-video-game-back-view-shown-big-screen-video45885438). Not only gun sways the same, as @TimmyJim stated, the scopes and a very quick scene with a red glare on the scopes are the same